# Sidekiq won't shut down after Ctrl+C

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq for background operations of my Rails 4.1 app.

When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to shutdown Sidekiq, Sidekiq catches the signal but seems to freeze after this last log line:

```
^C2014-09-18T16:17:19.194Z 20686 TID-ovwtinh0g INFO: Shutting down
2014-09-18T16:17:21.041Z 20686 TID-ovwtixflc INFO: Shutting down 5 quiet workers
```

Thus, I need another terminal window where I need to type:

```
bundle exec sidekiqctl stop pidfile
```

This is really inconvenient (and takes about 8 seconds) and I can't find why Sidekiq won't stop properly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

My conf is:

- Rails 4.1.5
- Sidekiq 3.2.4
- Postgresql DB

Comment: Instead of opening another terminal window you can also press `ctrl-z` to move sidekiq to the background. Then you can stop sidekiq with `sidekiqctl`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I came across this same issue.  Sidekiq 3.2.4 relies on the Celluloid gem at version 0.16.0, which partially breaks Sidekiq. See here: https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/issues/457

Update Sidekiq to 3.2.5 which locks Celluloid at version 0.15.2.

Comment: Still applicable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you have another thread in your Sidekiq process which is not stopping, maybe because you are [rescuing Exception](http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/03/03/the-perils-of-rescue-exception/).

Comment: I don't think this is my issue cause workers won't shut down nicely even when they all had no jobs to process in their whole lifetime.